# DynamoDB: set TTL into the items and also it shows time but record not deleted

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have set `ttl` as a TTL column and add epoch time on it for some items.

[image]

But I found that it is not getting deleted. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [AWS official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html)

> Depending on the size and activity level of a table, the actual delete operation of an expired item can vary. Because TTL is meant to be a background process, the nature of the capacity used to expire and delete items via TTL is variable (but free of charge). TTL typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration.

Using TTL for business critic operations is not recommended.

Comment: Nice answer - I'd just add, that you can still use TTL with business critical apps, if you also add a condition on your GetItem/Query, that the TTL may not be expired.